# Maximum size of xattr in OS X

Tags: json, macos, xattr

I would like to use xattr to store some meta-data on my files directly on the files. These are essentially tags that I use for the categorization of files when I do searches on them. My goal is to extend the usual Mac OS X tags by associating more info to each tag, for instance the date of addition of that tag and maybe other thing.

I was thinking to add an xattr to the files, using `xattr -w`. My first guess would be to store something like a JSON in this xattr value, but I was wondering

1) what are the limits of size I can store in an xattr? (man of xattr is vauge and refers to something called `_PC_XATTR_SIZE_BITS` which I cannot locate anywhere)

2) anything wrong with storing a JSON formatted string as an xattr?

Comment: I use the `tag` package in **homebrew** and I love it. You can add, delete and update tags on files very simply and see them in the Finder as well.

Comment: Hi, I know the package, but that works on standard OS X tags, those that you see and put in Finder. Here I am trying to make a new, customized set of tags. So I have to use `xattr`, I think. In any case the question remains, how large a data can the xattr hold?

Comment: It seems to be defined as 26 in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/unistd.h` but I don't think that means you can store 26 bits, or even the size of it may be no more than 26 bits. I think that because all the surrounding `#defines` are sequentially numbered around 26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to be able to write at least 260kB, like this by generating 260kB of nulls and converting them to the letter `a` so I can see them:

```
xattr -w myattr "$(dd if=/dev/zero bs=260000 count=1|tr '\0' a)" fred
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
260000 bytes transferred in 0.010303 secs (25235318 bytes/sec)
```

And then read them back with:

```
xattr -l fred 
myattr:  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaa
```

And check the length returned:

```
xattr -l fred | wc -c
260009
```

I suspect this is actually a limit of ARGMAX on the command line:

```
sysctl kern.argmax
kern.argmax: 262144
```

Also, just because you can store 260kB in an `xattr`, that does not mean it is advisable. I don't know about HFS+, but on some Unixy filesystems, the attributes can be stored directly in the inode, but if you go over a certain limit, additional space has to be allocated on disk for the data.

——-

With the advent of **High Sierra** and `APFS` to replace `HFS+`, be sure to test on both filesystems - also make sure that **Time Machine** backs up and restores the data as well and that utilities such as `ditto`, `tar` and the Finder propagate them when copying/moving/archiving files.

Also consider what happens when Email a tagged file, or copy it to a FAT-formatted USB Memory Stick.

---

I also tried setting multiple attributes on a single file and the following script successfully wrote 1,000 attributes (called `attr-0`, `attr-1` ... `attr-999`) each of 260kB to a single file - meaning that the file effectively carries 260MB of attributes:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((a=1;a<=1000;a++)) ; do
   echo Setting attr-$a
   xattr -w attr-$a "$(dd if=/dev/zero bs=260000 count=1 2> /dev/null | tr '\0' a)" fred
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo ERROR: Failed to set attr
      exit
   fi
done
```

These can all be seen and read back too - I checked.

Comment: Hi, this a good direct check, thanks. I was hoping one could read this from some man page, but of course a direct test also does the trick. Some useful info on how to preserve xattr is here https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/pages/extattrs.html

Comment: I have checked that using `cp` it does not preserve the xattr. In my cases even `cp -a` doesn't. It may be related to my use of GNU cp. Making a `duplicate` from Finder or Automator does preserve the xattr, including the non-standard one I am playing with.

Comment: ... and yes, `cp` from OS X (located in `/bin/cp`) preserves the xattrs by default

Comment: for now I have tests with long JSON strings, around 1.6 Kb if written to file, and it's holding pretty well.

Answer (score 5):

According to `man pathconf`, there is a “configurable system limit or option variable” called `_PC_XATTR_SIZE_BITS` which is

> the number of bits used to store maximum extended attribute size in bytes.  For
>   example, if the maximum attribute size supported by a file system is 128K, the value
>   returned will be 18.  However a value 18 can mean that the maximum attribute size can be
>   anywhere from (256KB - 1) to 128KB.  As a special case, the resource fork can have much
>   larger size, and some file system specific extended attributes can have smaller and preset
>   size; for example, Finder Info is always 32 bytes.

You can determine the value of this parameter using this small command line tool written in Swift 4:

```
import Foundation

let args = CommandLine.arguments.dropFirst()

guard let pathArg = args.first else {
  print ("File path argument missing!")
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE)
}

let v = pathconf(pathArg, _PC_XATTR_SIZE_BITS)

print ("_PC_XATTR_SIZE_BITS: \(v)")

exit (EXIT_SUCCESS)
```

I get:

- 31 bits for HFS+ on OS X 10.11
- 64 bits for APFS on macOS 10.13

as the number of bits used to store maximum extended attribute size. These imply that the actual maximum xattr sizes are somewhere in the ranges

- 1 GiB ≤ maximum < 2 GiB for HFS+ on OS X 10.11
- 8 EiB ≤ maximum < 16 EiB for APFS on macOS 10.13

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other relies on sheer guesswork.